# How to calculate probability that a random variable is less than the max of two other random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Suppose we have 3 random variables denoted $v_i$ that are i.i.d. on a uniform distribution such that $U[0,1]$. I want to know what is the probability that $v_1$ is higher than the maximum of the other two, in other words:$$Pr(v_1 \geq \max\{v_2,v_3\})$$

I start by noticing that we want to know what is the probability that $v_1$ is greater than $v_2$ and $v_3$, so we can rewrite this as:
$$Pr(v_1 \geq v_2 \text{ and } v_1 \geq v_3)$$
And since they are i.i.d, these probabilities are independent so,
$$Pr(v_1 \geq v_2 \text{ and } v_1 \geq v_3)=Pr(v_1 \geq v_2 )Pr(v_1 \geq v_2 )$$
But now I am stuck, since they are all random variables I cannot simply look at the CDF and see these values. Are my assumptions incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a straightforward proof.

Let $f(x)$ be the [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), $F(x)$ be the [cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

$P(X_n \ge \max_{1\le i\le n-1}X_i) = P(X_n \ge X_i, 1\le i\le n-1) = \int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} f(x_n)dx_n \; \Pi_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_{-\inf}^{x_n}f(x_i)dx_i = \int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} f(x_n)dx_n F^{n-1}(x_n)=\frac{1}{n}F^n(x_n)|_{-inf}^{+inf} = \frac{1}{n}.$

Since the random variable is continuous, it makes no difference between equality and inequality. So $P(X_n \ge \max_{1\le i\le n-1}X_i) = P(X_n >\max_{1\le i\le n-1}X_i) = P(X_n = \max_{1\le i\le n}X_i) = \frac{1}{n}.$

Note that the answer given by @copper.hat misses the pdf part.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M= \{ v | v_1 \ge v_2 \text{ and } v_1 \ge v_3 \}$ and
$1_M$ denote the indicator function.

$P[v_1 \ge v_2 \text{ and } v_1 \ge v_3] = \int_v 1_M(v) dv = \int_{v_1=0}^1 \int_{v_2=0}^{v_1} \int_{v_3=0}^{v_1} 1 dv = {1 \over 3}$.

This is not too surprising as one of the variables $v_1,v_2,v_3$ must be
the $\max$ and by symmetry none is favoured.

A word of caution regarding independence (or lack thereof): By a similar analysis we have $P[v_1 \ge v_2 ] = P[v_1 \ge v_3 ] = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: So these events are not independent, why not? Also, can you show how you setup your triple integral?

Comment: @tbone: The integral is just a matter of integrating the indicator function of the set in question, but the symmetry argument is equally appealing (the chances of two variables being equal are zero). Independence is a subtle concept, so it is hard to explain why, but notice that if you know that $v_1 \ge v_2$, then it is more likely that $v_1 \ge v_3$, so intuitively they are related in some way (specifically $P[v_1 \ge v_3 | v_1 \ge v_2] = {2 \over 3}$).

Comment: Note that the value of the symmetry argument is that it shows that if $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are iid. with a continuous distribution then the probability is ${ 1\over 3}$. The integral shows the same thing but requires more work.